# Dependency Injection to the constructor in MS Unit Test using Ninject

Tags: inversion-of-control, ninject, vs-unit-testing-framework

I would like to know is there way i could inject dependencies to the constructor of MS Unit Test class using the Ninject.

Here is the code snippet for repository

```
public Class StudentRepository : IRepository
{   
   SchoolContext schoolContext;

   public StudentRepository ()
   {
       schoolContext= new SchoolContext();
   } 

   public IEnumerable<Student> GetAll()
   {
       return DBContext.Students.ToList();
   }

}
```

here is the code for the IOC configuration

```
public class IocConfig
{
    public static void RegisterIoc()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<StudentRepository>();          
    }
}
```

Here is the code for MS Unit test.

```
[TestClass]
public Class StudentReposiotryTest    
{     

    public IRepository studentRepository;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void StudentReposiotryInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
        IocConfig.RegisterIoc();            
    }

     public StudentReposiotryTest(IRepository repository)
     {
         studentRepository= repository;
     }      


    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAllStudentsTest()
    {            
        List<Student> students =  studentRepository.GetAll();
        Assert.IsTrue(students.Count > 0);
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know MSTest has no hooks for DI.

But usually you shouldn't need to do so because Unit tests should be kept simple. Just inject Fakes/Mocks into the class under test this can easily be done without IoC container.